# Content going beyond page with sticky footer

Tags: html, css

I have a basic website with a header, content area and footer. I'm trying to create a sticky footer so when there is little content, the footer still stays at the bottom of the page. For some reason, when there is a lot of content, it just overflows beyond the browser and no scroll bar appears.

Here is the page in question:
http://swif.co/msb/page.html

I used many tutorials to get it working but the latest one I used was http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/.

Answer (score 1):

remove overflow:hidden from the body

Comment: Thank you so much, been working on this for hours and missed something so simple.